# SQL: summing the DATEDIFFs

Tags: mysql

using mysql

2 dates: `start_date` and `end_date`.

After altering the
`TIMEDIFF(start_date, end_date) AS time_diff`

I want to SUM() all time_diff so I try this
`SUM(TIMEDIFF(start_date, end_date)) AS time_diff`

this returning something I don't expect to.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
`SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, START_DATE)))) AS time_diff`

works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, START_DATE)))) AS time_diff`

Answer (score 0):

`end_date` should be first and `start_date` second otherwise you will get negative values as output:

```
SUM(TIME_DIFF(CAST(end_date AS DATETIME), CAST(start_date AS DATETIME))) AS time_diff
```

Comment: Thank you for saying this, but it's not helped.<br>This is what I see before the SUM()<br>`672:00:00` and `01:30:00` I should SUM them<br>then after<br>`SUM(TIME_DIFF(end_date, start_date)) AS time_diff`<br>returns<br>`6759000.000000` and what I expect to is `673:30:00`